# I did not reach upvote rep limit, yet I did not get my +10 for an upvote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53268/ron-gordon?tab=reputation).  Just curious, as I do not understand why the system did not record the +10 rep points for this upvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Your post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/350758/264) (which I assume is the one you're referring to) was made CW (community wiki) due to your editing it 10 times: <strike>[see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/350758/12) where the system recorded this occurring</strike>, and [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/161783) for the official explanation of the policy.

(*now that the CW status has been removed, the record is no longer present*)

Once a post is CW, it does not affect its owner's reputation. However, moderators can remove CW status if there's good reason; I've just done so for your post. You won't get the 10 points from the upvote that occurred while it was CW, but you will get the points from any future upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I'm still a newbie at this, I guess.  I appreciate your taking the time to look into this.

Comment: No problem - there's certainly a lot of intricacies to the Stack Exchange network to get used to.